# Have any psionic-specific adventures or modules ever been published for D&D by TSR or WotC?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, psionics

Have any psionic-specific adventures or modules ever been published for D&D by TSR or WotC?

Any edition is fine, as my impression is that there are not really any. Answers are preferred to be limited to official (or sources deemed official at any point in time of history, even if they are no longer considered official or canon) TSR or WotC material (Thus, Dungeon, Dragon, Official sites such as Athas.org, Kalamar, etc., are all official).

I'm looking to see if TSR or WotC has ever published adventures where the encounters are all psionic based, or at least the majority of them are.

Comment: Using psionic items, powers, effects, and creatures as the majority of the encounter components? And not using magical effects, unless unavoidable? Or does that not clarify my goal?

Comment: @NautArch how would you suggest I rephrase it then? I'm really not trying to shop, more attempting to prove a negative: to wit, that no purely psionic adventures were ever officially published....

Comment: Asking for a reasonably-sized, finite, fixed list is fine, which is what this question is doing. It’s not asking for recommendations or for any kind of “best” option, which means it isn’t a shopping question and the problems with shopping questions aren’t going to be problems here.

Comment: I'm not sure about *purely* psionic, but the entirety of the Dark Sun setting featured psionics more heavily than magic. I would suggest that, if any purely psionic adventures exist, they will be set in Dark Sun.

Comment: @Adeptus In theory that should have been the case... in practice, however, things did not turn out that way. There appear to have been more magic related things published in Dark Sun than there were psionic, sadly. My own personal experiences echo this, almost everyone seemingly wanted to be a Templar flunky, or Defiler who ignored everything to go hog wild, or a secret Preserver living on the edge....

Answer (score 5):

### *Death of Lashimire*

This was a psionics based adventure published in *[Dungeon Magazine issue 116](https://annarchive.com/files/Dungeon%20Magazine%20%23116.pdf)*, with the description of:

> The infamous psion Lashimire is dead, leaving an undefended fortress ripe for looting. But the PC's soon discover that they aren't the only ones after Lashimire's treasure when they begin to encounter bands of githyanki in search of a missing silver sword. A D&D psionics adventure for 12th level characters.

In addition, [this 2005 thread on Morrus's Unofficial](https://www.enworld.org/threads/dungeon-any-psionic-adventures.124450/) claimed that there would be an adventure a year published in Dungeon centered around psionics, but whether that actually happened I can't find out.

Answer (score 3):

The Garden of Nefaron in Dragon magazine #53.
Unique in the fact that the background mentions mighty heroes that used their psionic powers to imprison the evil psionic wizard and to complete the dungeon you have to be pretty evil to fight and kill the guardian Ki-rin. Also, a new magic item for psionics only, the psychogems.